# Using closures in Java to do a countdown

Tags: java, android, canvas, closures

I am writing an app for android. The app has many graphics moving around a canvas. If two meet they "explode". In a nutshell, I have a nice couple of graphics for explosions, however the nature of an explosion is that it only lasts for a split seocnd, or a little longer, and I need to program the explosion-graphic to show on the screen and then disappear. I have some clumsy code to implement this.

```
  public void flickerExplosion(){

                flickercounter++;
                if(flickercounter ==100){

                    flickercounter = 0;
                                    explode_graphic.deleteGraphic();
                            }

                if(flickercounter%10>4){

                        explode_graphic.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.exp1));

                    }

                    else{explode_graphic.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.exp2));}

            }
```

In the code, explode_graphic is a class for holding a bitmap which is drawn on the canvas by onDraw(). After incrementing 100 times the explosion graphic goes away. The explosion flickers between two bitmaps exp1, exp2.
The code works OK. I realize I could have used a timer(), orother such class increment. But my question is about a **niggling feeling I'm wasting resources with flickercounter**, which is a class int variable.
For iterating things like this, is it possible to use anon inner functions (i.e. closures)? If so would that make the class variable flickercounter obsolete and make my program more efficient?
I ask this as someone who only started learning about closures a week ago.

Comment: Java doesn't have anonymous inner functions -- they have anonymous inner classes which only vaguely approximate closures.

Answer (score 0):

A. Java can't do anonymous functions.

B. [Premature Optimization is the root of all Evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Don't assume something is performing terribly, test it!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of projects that provide this type of functionality. Read this for some background and refs to the major contenders:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-closures.html